# Slow MySQL Query / Large DB / JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, database

is there any way to optimize the following MySql Query?

```
SELECT article.*
FROM article
WHERE channelid = 1
AND ((SELECT count(*) FROM article_cCountry WHERE ID1 = article.id AND ID2 = 1) = 1)
AND date < now()
AND released = "TRUE"
AND ( (uId = 0) OR ((SELECT count(*) FROM user WHERE ID = article.uId and released = true) = 1) )
ORDER BY cDate DESC
LIMIT 20
```

I have already tried to use INNER JOIN for the article_cCountry check but the performance was even worse.

**EDIT**

*Structure for article_cCountry*

```
| ID | ID1 | ID2 |   (ID1 => article.id, ID2 => country)
```

*Structure for user user*

About 20 columns with user data

Comment: cant u help us help u by providing the table structure for related tables ?

Comment: is the query for `selecting all article with channelid = 1 and date before now and is released and only from spesific country which only have 1 article and shown only for user who wrote it is released which only write 1 or else no user wrote it. ` ?
try to use online testing for query, so you can put your tables there, cant see much from only this information

Comment: yes, but: with the "SELECT count(*)...= 1", I meant "Articles from this country" as the count(*) will return 0 if the article is not from country "1". The same applies to the user query

Comment: never! never use subqueries in WHERE condition!

Comment: This schema is nuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to explain your query with:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT ...
```

If you are not using any index try to put an index on the fields used in the where:

```
article.date
article.channelid
article.released
user.released
article_cCountry.id1
article_cCountry.id2
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you need to check

```
SELECT article.*, COUNT(ac.id) ac_count, COUNT(u.id) u_count
FROM article
  INNER JOIN article_cCountry ac ON ac.ID1 = article.id AND ac.ID2 = 1
  INNER JOIN user u ON u.ID = article.uId and u.released
WHERE 
  channelid = 1
  AND date < now()
  AND released = "TRUE"
GROUP BY article.id
HAVING ac_count = 1 AND (uId = 0 OR u_count = 1)
ORDER BY cDate DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

> SELECT 
>     article.* 
>   FROM
>     article 
>     INNER JOIN article_cCountry 
>       ON article.id = article_cCountry.ID1 
>     INNER JOIN `USER` 
>       ON article.uId = `USER`.ID 
>   WHERE channelid = 1 
>     AND article_cCountry.ID2 = 1 
>     AND `USER`.released = TRUE 
>     AND DATE < NOW() 
>     AND released = TRUE 
>   ORDER BY cDate DESC 
>   LIMIT 20 ;

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your subqueries in to temporary tables

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE COUNTRY
(
    countryCount INT,
    articleId INT
)
INSERT INTO
    COUNTRY
SELECT
    COUNT(1),
    ID1,
FROM
    article_cCountry
WHERE
    ID2 = 1
GROUP BY
    ID1

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE USERS
(
    userCount INT,
    articleId INT
)
INSERT INTO
    USERS
SELECT
    COUNT(1),
    ID
FROM
    [user]
WHERE
    released = true
GROUP BY
    ID

SELECT 
    article.*
FROM 
    article JOIN COUNTRY country ON country.articleId = article.id
        JOIN USERS users ON users.articleId = article.uId
WHERE 
    channelid = 1
AND 
    --((SELECT count(*) FROM article_cCountry WHERE ID1 = article.id AND ID2 = 1) = 1)
    country.countryCount = 1
AND 
    date < now()
AND 
    released = "TRUE"
AND 
    ( 
        (uId = 0) 
    OR 
        --((SELECT count(*) FROM user WHERE ID = article.uId and released = true) = 1))
        (users.userCount = 1)
    )
ORDER BY 
    cDate DESC
LIMIT 20

DROP TABLE COUNTRY;
DROP TABLE USERS;
```